# How to find a specific part of a link in page source with python

Tags: python-3.x

```
<iframe src="https://secure.soundcloud.com/web-auth?client_id=EsiVJzOTNkZdcfQL0nbifcrQdmMnR61R&amp;device_id=312440-609464-697869-8080" sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms" class="webAuthContainer__iframe" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="500">
</iframe>
```

I'm trying to get the client_id= from this line above in the page source from a soundcloud.com endpoint using python.

Soundcloud client_id's change very often and I would like to visit this page every time I run my script to retrieve the new one.
So I'm looking to have `EsiVJzOTNkZdcfQL0nbifcrQdmMnR61R` saved to a variable in this case, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it as im pretty new to python.

I would like to give the `re` module a try but it's very overwhelming as im still very new

Comment: Looks like you answered your question: indeed, you can use regular expressions with the `re` module.

Comment: For example, `"client_id=([^&]+)&"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """
<iframe src="https://secure.soundcloud.com/web-auth?client_id=EsiVJzOTNkZdcfQL0nbifcrQdmMnR61R&amp;device_id=312440-609464-697869-8080" sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms" class="webAuthContainer__iframe" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="500">
</iframe>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser").find("iframe")
id_value = re.search(r"client_id=([^&]+)&", soup["src"]).group(1)
print(id_value)
```

Output:

```
EsiVJzOTNkZdcfQL0nbifcrQdmMnR61R
```